# Regex exclude doesn't exclude string only first character

Tags: javascript, regex

Firstly we have the following string:

```
aaa{ignoreme}asdebla bla f{}asdfdsaignoreme}asd
```

We want our regex to find the whitespaces and any special charsacters like `{}`, but if after `{` comes exactly `ignoreme}` then exclude it

This is where we are right now:

```
(?!{ignoreme})[\s\[\]{}()<>\\'"|^`]
```

The problem is that our regex finds the `}` after ignoreme

Here is the link https://regex101.com/r/bU1oG0/2

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is that the `}` is matched since your `(?!{ignoreme})` lookahead only skips a `{` followed with `ignoreme}` and matches a `}` since it is not starting a `{ignoreme}` char sequence. Also, in JS, you cannot use a lookbehind, like `(?<!{ignoreme)}`.

This is a kind of issue that can be handled with a regex that matches what you do not need, and matches and *captures* what you need:

```
/{ignoreme}|([\s[\]{}()<>\\'"|^`])/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fP6zY2/1)

Now, `{ignoreme}` is matched (and you do not have to use this value) and `` ([\s[]{}()<>\\'"|^`]) `` is captured into Group 1 the value of which you need to use.

Comment: I am waiting for "but I need..." comment.

Comment: No "but I need ..." comment because I had a wrong approach to the problem. I wanted to make it with negated lookahead (?!). This is way much easier.

Comment: Yes, the point is that you actually needed a lookbehind, but JS regex engine does not support this construct. :(

Comment: It is a different pattern and input, but the same construct and concept: the `(?!{{ignoreme})` lookahead restricts a generic character class following it in the pattern so that the character class cannot match a character that starts the character sequence specified inside the lookahead. It is part of the [**tempered greedy token**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970), you can read a bit more on that there. So, the first `{` in `aaa{{ignoreme}asd` is not matched, but the second `{` after the first one is matched because it does not start a `{{ignoreme}` char sequence.

Comment: Thanks for everything, Have a nice day